# How can I change my MongoDB IP address to another than 0.0.0.0/0?

Tags: mongodb, sqlite, networking, ip

I'm trying to develop a telegram bot using `aiogram`. I used SQLite as a database. So I need to use MongoDB because it is fast, free and simple to use. I need help with an IP. In Network Access IP is 0.0.0.0/0 which showed as below:
[image: Network Access IP]

That works, but it isn't safety to users. I'm trying to change an IP address, but the bot don't connect to database MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

Open the MongoDB configuration file (/etc/mongod.conf) in your preferred text editor and use the following properties:

```
. . .
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1

. . .
```

Then restart service. See [IP Binding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-mongodb-configuration/) for more info

Or run the following `mongod` command to bind to both the localhost and the hostname My-Example-Associated-Hostname:

```
mongod --bind_ip localhost,My-Example-Associated-Hostname
```